# how to compare numeric fields in two files with awk

Tags: bash, awk

i have these two files :
file1

```
2537

1279

1075

12799

1474

135441

1260

1169

1281

10759
```

and 
file2

```
1070,1279960511,BR,USA,UNITED STATES
1278,1279960511,US,USA,UNITED STATES
1279,1279960527,CA,CAN,CANADA
1289,1279967231,US,USA,UNITED STATES
2679,1279971327,CA,CAN,CANADA
1279,1279971839,US,USA,UNITED STATES
1279,1279972095,CA,CAN,CANADA
1279,1279977471,US,USA,UNITED STATES
127997,1279977983,CA,CAN,CANADA
127997,1279980159,US,USA,UNITED STATES
127998,1279980543,CA,CAN,CANADA
107599,1075995007,US,USA,UNITED STATES
107599,1075995023,VG,VGB,VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH
107599,1075996991,US,USA,UNITED STATES
107599,1075997071,CA,CAN,CANADA
```

i want to : for each entry of file1 go through first column of file2 and when the value in this column become bigger than out "file1" element then return the 3rd element of file2
i have tried many manyy ways but none worked i either get an empty file or it print something diff than i expect 
my last try is :

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN {FS="," ; i=1 ; while (getline < "file2") { x[i] = $1 ; y[i] = $3 ; i++ }}

{ a[$1] = $1 ; h=1 ; while (x[h] <= a[$1]) { h++ } ; { print y[h] }}' file1
```

but this runs forever it doesnt stop neither gives anything
help me plzzz this has been killing me for days now and i am giving up 
thanks

Desired output :

```
#this is a comment and i ll write file 2 as if it was a matrix  

because file1[1] > file2[1,1] ... and file1[1] > file2[2,1] .... and file1[1] > file2[3,1] ... and file1[1] > file2[4,1] but file1[1] < file2[5,1] ... then print file2[4,3] ... which is "US"

now go to file1[2] :

file[2] > file2[1,1] ... and file1[2] > file2[2,1] ... but file1[2] <= file2[3,1] ... then print file2[3,3]
```

in summary i want to print : "the third elemenent (col) of the first line (from file2) the file1 element first becomes > the first element of next line (file2)

Comment: I think you must have meant the 3rd element of file2?

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to do? The lowest number in the first list is 1075 and in the second list it is 1070. So except for the 1070 every line in the second list qualifies the criteria you have listed.

Comment: no i want only the entry for the "first" match or first time file1[i]>file2[j] and then quit the loop and go to file1[i+1]
"the 3rd element of file 2 is wht i meant thankks :))

Comment: please edit your question to include your required output, given the inputs you have shown. Good luck.

Comment: @amit_g well not every line qualifies the criteria for instance :
for the first line of file1 my loop should skip the first 3 elements of col1(file2) and give me "us" 
 for file1[2] it should skip only the first two elements and give me "ca" and so on

Comment: @shellter 
thats done i hope its enough

Comment: I think this is the desired output (can't put newlines in comments):
2537 CA
1279 US
1075 US
12799 CA
1474 CA
1260 US
1169 US
1281 US
10759 CA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Long one-liner:

Here's one way you can do this:

```
cat file1|grep -vE '^$'|while read min; do cat file2|while read line; do val=$(echo $line|cut -d, -f1); if [ $min -lt $val ]; then short_country=$(echo $line|cut -d, -f3); echo $min: $short_country "($val)"; break; fi; done; done
```

This yields the output

```
2537: CA (2679)
1279: US (1289)
1075: US (1278)
12799: CA (127997)
1474: CA (2679)
1260: US (1278)
1169: US (1278)
1281: US (1289)
10759: CA (127997)
```

## Explanation

Instead of making this a one-liner, it's easier to understand if you break it down in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat file1 |                               # read file1
grep -E '^[0-9]+$' |                      # filter out lines in file1 that don't just contain a number
while read min; do                        # for each line in file1:
  cat file2 |                               # read file2
  grep -E '^([0-9]+,){2}[A-Z]{2},' |        # filter out lines in file2 that don't match the right format
  while read line; do                       # for each line in file2:
    val=$(echo $line|cut -d, -f1)             # pull out $val: the first comma-delimited value
    if [ $min -lt $val ]; then                # if it's greater than the $min value read from file1:
      short_country=$(echo $line|cut -d, -f3)   # get the $short_country from the third comma-delimited value in file2
      echo "$min: $short_country ($val)"        # print it to stdout. You can get rid of ($val) here if you're not interested in it.
      break                                     # Now that we've found a value in file2, stop this loop and go to the next line in file1
    fi
  done
done
```

Since you didn't originally specify your output format, I guessed. Hopefully it's useful to you this way.

Comment: thankks do explain plzz i am still trying to understand what u did here

Comment: Explanation finished - let me know if you have questions about it

Comment: @rima : nimbus's output was the sort of example I was hoping you provide. Do see how it is easier to understand your requirement when the output is clearly stated, and not just a further text of 'I need this and then this and then this and ...' :-) In the future, please realise that you're asking people to spend their time to help you solve your problem and giving a clear definition of what you need will get you an answer more quickly. Good luck.

Comment: @nilbus very nice but i get a "-bash: [: 1279: unary operator expected" error before every output line

Comment: @ shellter i am sorry my bad i am new here my very first time 
i ll keep that in mind :)  thx

Comment: Hmm... that would be happening if either $var or $min was not a number when it tries to do the -lt (less than) comparison. I'll modify the script to account for that.

Comment: Done. The script version now uses grep to only process lines in file1 and file2 that match your spec. It was probably blank lines in file2 that was causing your problem.

Comment: Yet another [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).  `grep` can take filenames as arguments directly.  `cat` does absolutely nothing here.

Comment: True. I was using cat in an earlier edit before I stuck in grep, which is why it ended up there.

Comment: i couldnt edit ur script is it the spacing? when i past it anywhere else and then to my terminal it goes all wrong
  it seems to work great but i need it to be 
2537: US (2679)

1279: CA (1289)

1075: BR (1278)

12799: US (127997)

1474: US (2679)

1260: BR (1278)

1169: BR (1278)

1281: CA (1289)

10759: US (127997)

instead and the if statement should have -le

Comment: You're not pasting #!/bin/bash into the terminal, are you? That line is meant to be the first line of a script. You also might try removing the comments from each line to see if that helps.

Comment: @nilbus  a very small edit did it :

cat file1 | grep -vE '^$' | while read min; do cat file2 | while read line; do val=$(echo $line|cut -d, -f1); previous=$short_country; short_country=$(echo $line|cut -d, -f3); if [ $min -lt $val ]; then echo $min: $previous "($val)"; break; fi; done; done

i just added the "previous" var 

thxxx thxx alott more than i can say

Comment: Useless use of cat: `grep -vE '^$' < file | ...`

Answer (score 2):

I took your AWK script as a basis for the following. I changed variable names to make them more meaningful since this helps with self-documentation.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=","
    count = 1
    while (getline < "file2") {
        key[count] = $1
        countrycode[count] = $3
        count++
    }
}

{
    for (idx = 1; idx <= count; idx++)
    {
        if ($1 < key[idx]) {
            print countrycode[idx]
            next
        }
    }
}
```

Example run (printing `$0` instead of just `$3` - the code above only prints `$3`):

```
$ sort -n -k1,1 -t, file2 > tmp; mv tmp file2
$ ./scannums file1
2679,1279971327,CA,CAN,CANADA
1289,1279967231,US,USA,UNITED STATES
1278,1279960511,US,USA,UNITED STATES
127997,1279977983,CA,CAN,CANADA
2679,1279971327,CA,CAN,CANADA
1278,1279960511,US,USA,UNITED STATES
1278,1279960511,US,USA,UNITED STATES
1289,1279967231,US,USA,UNITED STATES
127997,1279977983,CA,CAN,CANADA
```

Note that nothing is printed for the value 135441 from file1 since nothing from file2 meets the criteria.

If you prefer, this could be made into a one-liner.

Comment: i really dont understand how it does this 
what i could get is that when $1 is <= key [indx] then print .. it should print country code for all values where $1 satisfies this 
clearly thats not the case so plzz help me understand this last loop

Comment: @rima: Please edit your question to show the actual output that your sample data should give (also include the corresponding full line from file2 so we can see how they should match). Please indicate whether the files are or should be sorted. It's really difficult to follow your array-like notation. Based on a comment I found attached to another answer (the information should be edited into the question), I've changed my answer to use `<` instead of `<=` and assumed that file1 is not sorted but file2 is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
sort -n -t"," -k1,1 file1 file2 | awk -F"," '{if ($3 != "") {s = $3;} else {print $1 " " s;}}'
```

produces

```
1075 BR
1169 BR
1260 BR
1279 US
1281 US
1474 US
2537 US
10759 CA
12799 CA
135441 CA
```

If the original order in file1 is important, the below can be used

```
awk '{print NR "," $1}' file1 file2 | sort -t"," -n -k 2,2 | awk -F"," '{if ($4 != "") {s = $4;} else {print $1 " " s;}}' | sort -t"," -k1,1 | cut -d" " -f2
```

produces

```
US
CA
BR
BR
US
CA
US
BR
CA
US
```

Comment: That's actually very clever and concise. I like it.

Comment: 1279 CA
1281 CA
10759 US
12799 CA
10759 US
135441 unknown

my file2 is already sorted in ascending order by its first column (my sample is not which u shouldnt consider) my file2 is not sorted

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use `xargs` for the "read file1" part of your assignment? The single "seek value in file2" part is very simple in awk, and you avoid the double file pointers...

Edit: example of using xargs and awk.

```
cat file1 | xargs awk '$1 > ARGV[2] {print $3; return}' file2
```

Edit: This example works (tried on my computer now...)

Use -n 1 as option to xargs to pass exactly one argument in each pass. Remove the "val" arg after storing it, so AWK gets just the filename (file2) and knows what to do. Flag when found, return does not exist.

```
cat file1 | xargs -n 1 awk -F, 'BEGIN {val = ARGV[2]; ARGC--; found=0} $1 > val {if (found==0) { print val, $3; found = 1}}' file2
```

Edit: shorter version

```
cat file1 | xargs -n 1 awk -F, 'BEGIN {val = ARGV[2]; ARGC--} (!found) && ($1 > val)  {print val, $3; found = 1}' file2
```

Script version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  val = ARGV[2]
  ARGC--
}
(!found) && ($1 <= val) {
  # cache 3rd column of previous line
  prev = $3
}
(!found) && ($1 > val) {
  # print cached value as soon as we cross the limit
  print val, prev
  found = 1
}
```

name it find_val.awk and chmod +x it. The you con just do `find_val.awk somefile somevalue` and use xargs the same way

```
cat file1 | xargs -n 1 find_val.awk file2
```

Comment: with xargs how?? this is not the only file just a sample of long and many files and i know the seek value is simple and its wht i am trying to do but still its not working for me

Comment: This is not an answer to his question. This sort of thing would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: I have the feeling the OP is trying to use the wrong tools for the job. So for me this is a solution to the proposed problem.

Comment: i dont know of any other option  i am not that good with commands but i have spent too much time with awk that i have no more time to start with something else
i also tried to go with only bash but dead end

Comment: plz dont think i am ignoring anything i am still processing this thank you alll :)) happy to find peoples like u

Comment: this gives the countrycode where file1 element is > file2[1,1] while i want the countrycode right before that 
Right before it becomes a sup sign

Comment: What if there is no "right before"? Assuming it always exist, i'm changing the answer as per your request.

Comment: actually this : "   cat file1 | xargs -n 1 awk -F, 'BEGIN {val = ARGV[2]; ARGC--} { i=1; if ($1 <= val) {a[i] = $3 ; i++} print val,a[i]}' file2
   " does exactly wht i want but prints the output too many times how can i overcome that ?
thx

Comment: If you want the "last" valid value you have to print it when you know it's the last one. Awk does not know anything but the current line and the values of the variables you have set before. So you have to print in the first "non-valid" line.

Comment: Useless use of cat: `xargs ... < file1`